# Checking if Type instance is a nullable enum in C#

Tags: c#, enums, nullable

How do i check if a Type is a nullable enum in C#
something like

```
Type t = GetMyType();
bool isEnum = t.IsEnum; //Type member
bool isNullableEnum = t.IsNullableEnum(); How to implement this extension method?
```

Answer (score 204, accepted):

```
public static bool IsNullableEnum(this Type t)
{
    Type u = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
    return (u != null) && u.IsEnum;
}
```

Answer (score 46):

EDIT: I'm going to leave this answer up as it will work, and it demonstrates a few calls that readers may not otherwise know about. However, [Luke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723048/checking-if-type-instance-is-a-nullable-enum-in-c/2723100#2723100) is definitely nicer - go upvote it :)

You can do:

```
public static bool IsNullableEnum(this Type t)
{
    return t.IsGenericType &&
           t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) &&
           t.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsEnum;
}
```

Comment: I think I'd have done it Luke's way; less complex for the caller.

Comment: @Marc: I don't see how it makes any odds for the *caller* - but Luke's way is certainly nicer than mine.

Comment: Yeah definitely keep it for future reference

Comment: Yeah.  I would have done "public static bool IsNullableEnum(object value) { if (value == null) { return true; } Type t = value.GetType(); return /* same as Jon's return */ ; }" because it may work with boxed types.  And then overloaded with LukeH answer for better performance.

Answer (score 32):

As from C# 6.0 the accepted answer can be refactored as

```
Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t)?.IsEnum == true
```

The == true is needed to convert bool? to bool

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool IsNullable(this Type type)
{
    return type.IsClass
        || (type.IsGeneric && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition == typeof(Nullable<>));
}
```

I left out the `IsEnum` check you already made, as that makes this method more general.

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx