# My Enum is not recognized using reflection and PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, enums

I've a audit class that recovery everything by reflection. I need in my actual point know if an specific property is an Enum, but I'm getting a strange behavior:

During foreach iteration `q.PropertyType.IsEnum` return false. And using Quick watcher the property is really false, and the IsClass too. So this is basically nothing :)

Studying a little more about the problem I found that Nullable Enum returns false in `IsEnum`. How can I ignore this nullable and verify if the property is an enum or not?

Comment: Nit: The numbers from 30-39 are spelled "Thirty", not "Thirdy".

Comment: @Custódio what's `ReflectionUtil` ?

Comment: We might need to know how you are aquiring the `q` you mention in your question.

Comment: @Bala R, @ Jan-Peter Vos I've edited the question to be more complete.

Comment: still too little information. Show complete code. Where is allProperties declared?

Comment: Your question is asking about a PropertyInfo property.  But no property is visible in the snippet.  What is there works fine.

Comment: @jgauffin.. in my answer. But you can infer this. "allProperties" right?

Comment: @Hans Passant, I'm getting all PropertyInfo inside an array, and then I can see the `PropertyType`in snippet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IsEnum will return `false` when your property is of a nullable type. In this case, calling [Nullable.GetUnderlyingType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx) on `q.PropertyType` will return the type you want. Then you can check with IsEnum.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I've tried your enum, and it is fetchable.  A call to Foo.GetEnumProperties returns an array with "TestProp" in it:

```
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        [XmlEnumAttribute("Twenty and Something")]
        TwentyTree = 1,
        [XmlEnumAttribute("Thirty and Something")]
        Thirdyfour
    }

    class Foo
    {
        public MyEnum TestProp { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// Get a list of properties that are enum types 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <returns>Enum property names</returns>
        public static string[] GetEnumProperties()
        {
            MemberInfo[] members = typeof(Foo).FindMembers(MemberTypes.Property, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance, null, null);
            List<string> retList = new List<string>();
            foreach (MemberInfo nextMember in members)
            {
                PropertyInfo nextProp = nextMember as PropertyInfo;
                if (nextProp.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                    retList.Add(nextProp.Name);
            } return retList.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

To do what you are trying to do, I use System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute, then you can fetch it like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the description for the enum
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">Value to check</param>
/// <returns>The description</returns>
public static string GetDescription(object value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    string name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
    if (name != null)
    {
        FieldInfo field = type.GetField(name);
        if (field != null)
        {
            DescriptionAttribute attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
            if (attr != null)
            {
                string desc = attr.Description;
                return desc;
            }
        }
    }
    return value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The question aims discover what's wrong with MyEnum declaration.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your enum declaration.  You are just going about getting the attribute in a way that won't work.

Comment: Nice. So, to adapt to my question what's the better way to return a bool value saying if a Property is Enum or not

Comment: You mean you have a class foo, and the class has properties, and you want to check its properties to see which ones are enum types?

Comment: I modified my answer in case that's what you wanted.

Comment: Yes. allProperties mentioned in question represent everything of a generic object that my audit class receive. So I want to recognize the enum type

Comment: OK. Let me know if this latest code answers your question.  Thanks.

Comment: I did the first part already. The difference is that you have used `q.GetType().IsEnum`, I'm using `q.PropertyType.IsEnum`. I'm testing to verify if it works.

Comment: Oops, sorry, it was supposed to be nextProp.PropertyType.IsEnum.  This works fine for me on my own classes.  Not sure why it would not work for yours.  Have you tried changing from XmlEnumAttribute to DescriptionAttribute?

Comment: Well, this is possible. But nonviable right now, every enum in whole system use XmlAttribute

Comment: I tried the code on your enum, and it works too.  I've edited my answer again.

Comment: @AvesAvatar! I guess I found! my enum is declared as nullable.

Comment: The enum you had in your original question was not nullable.

Comment: I don't put the part the code where I declare the Enum, but the problem was nullable. After use skeet solution everything works.

Answer (score 0):

The general problem with not recognized Enums is that they can be Nullable and then the `IsEnum` doesn't work.
This is the case here, and using a @Skeet answer [Checking if Type instance is a nullable enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723048/checking-if-type-instance-is-a-nullable-enum-in-c) I solve my problem.