# IsEnum does not recognise enum

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, enums

My code is .Net 4.0 and I am trying to understand some legacy code I now work with. I can't change it at the moment and i'm sure this code has worked before my time. It needs to make an `enum` from `strings`, but the type is not recognized as an `enum`.

---

**EDIT**

I now realize the `enum` property is actually `nullable`. So it is a `NetType`? How can I convert that into an `enum` if it has a value?

When I debug and see the type that is being checked on the `enum`, this is what I see:

> FullName = System.Nullable`1[[AppName.Model.NetType, AppName.Model,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>
>   Name = Nullable`1

This is the `enum`:

```
public enum NetType
{
    ChoiceOne = 1,
    ChoiceTwo = 2
}
```

Main code, simplified for clarity:

```
var property = typeof(MainClass).GetProperty("NetType");
var value = GetValue(property.PropertyType, "ChoiceOne");

private object GetValue(Type type, string valueString)
{
     if (type.IsEnum)// Why false?
         return Enum.Parse(type, valueString);

     if (type == typeof (Int32))
         return Int32.Parse(valueString);

     return valueString;
 }
```

Comment: Looks to me like the type is `NetType?` which is not an enum, but a struct containing one

Comment: Oh snap! Thats true :o 
So how can i properly identify that as an enum and parse it?

Comment: what about using enum.IsDefined()

Comment: You'll need to check if `type` is a `Nullable<T>` and then check whether it's generic type argument `T`is an enum. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723048/checking-if-type-instance-is-a-nullable-enum-in-c-sharp) has the specifics to get you started.

Comment: Why do we not see the definition of `MainClass` in this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if Type instance is a nullable enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723048/checking-if-type-instance-is-a-nullable-enum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @KirkLarkin that did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType()` to check to see if it's a nullable enum first.  If it is, use the underlying enum; if it's not, do your checks as you normally did.

```
private object GetValue(Type type, string valueString)
{
    // If Nullable.GetUnderlyingType() returns null, it's not nullable
    // and you can default to type.
    var enumCandidiate = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type;

    if (enumCandidiate.IsEnum)
        return Enum.Parse(enumCandidiate, valueString);

     if (type == typeof (Int32))
         return Int32.Parse(valueString);

     return valueString;
}
```

Here was my test script (using RoslynPad, hence the `Dump()` calls).

```
var val = GetValue(typeof(NetType), "ChoiceOne");
val.Dump();

val = GetValue(typeof(NetType?), "ChoiceOne");
val.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var type = property.PropertyType;
object value;
if (type.IsEnum)
{
    value = GetValue(type, "ChoiceOne");
}
else if (type.IsGenericType &&
    type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) &&
    type.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsEnum)
{
    value = GetValue(type.GetGenericArguments()[0], "ChoiceOne");
}
```

It should work for both `NetType` and `NetType?`.