# How to check if value is null or an Enum object without throwing an error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What is a one line expression I can use to check if response.TrackReply.HighestSeverity is null or of type NotificantionSeverityType? I'm getting an Error with the code below when response.TrackReply.HighestSeverity is null.
I would like to set it to null when it is null and when it is of type NotificationEventType to the appropriate enum string value.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string HighestSeverity = Enum.GetName(response.TrackReply.HighestSeverity);
        }
    }

    public enum NotificationSeverityType
    {

        /// <remarks/>
        ERROR,

        /// <remarks/>
        FAILURE,

        /// <remarks/>
        NOTE,

        /// <remarks/>
        SUCCESS,

        /// <remarks/>
        WARNING,
    }
```

Comment: `response?.TrackReply?.HighestSeverityEnum == null ? null : Enum.GetName(response.TrackReply.HighestSeverity);`?

Comment: What data type is `HighestSeverity`? Can you make it a Nullable NotificationSeverityType? That would solve a lot of problems.

Comment: Why not add `NONE`, `UNKNOWN`, or something similar as the first item in the enum?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723048/checking-if-type-instance-is-a-nullable-enum-in-c-sharp